# Latex numbering paragraphs - solution

Tags: xetex, luatex, numbering, paragraphs

This seems to be a favourite I thought I'd post my solution and see if there can be improvements

So digging around I see references to `parano` which has dropped off the interwebs - though I found a copy [here](https://github.com/HugoAreias/DRAW--includes-DREQL-/blob/master/Manual/parano.sty) - trying it was a bit of a car crash - which is not surprising since it was apparently very beta

I did get a good step forward [here](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/numpara.shtml#sec:numpara) - but it was ever so slightly off - and I spent a few hours wasted trying to do something with marginpar to avoid having to do a negative parindent - **I would still like to avoid that negative parindent**

Here is my MWE that works for me now - note due to the parindent kludge low digits don't work properly - the counter takes the chapter number and the paragraph number

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=3.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm, marginparwidth=20pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\newcounter{para}
\newcommand*{\numberedparagraph}{%
  {\color{gray}\textit{\thechapter.\refstepcounter{para}\thepara}\space}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{-25pt} 

\makeatletter

\preto\chapter{\everypar{}}
\preto\section{\everypar{}}
\preto\subsection{\everypar{}}
\preto\subsubsection{\everypar{}}

\renewcommand{\@afterheading}{%
  \@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty\@M
      \if@afterindent
      \else
        {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
      \fi
    \else
      \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
      \everypar{\numberedparagraph}%
    \fi
    \numberedparagraph
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\chapter{title}

\section{Sample Section}

\lipsum[1-4]

\subsection{Sample Subsection}

\lipsum[11-15]

\section{Another Section}

\lipsum[16-18]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code wraps the paragraph number in a box and then moves the box to the left margin. The result does not depend on font size or fixed negative spaces.

You can choose the height of the numbers and their color.

[image: c]

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=3.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm, marginparwidth=20pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

%*****************************************************  changed<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the margins  <<<<<<

\newcounter{para}
\preto\chapter{\everypar{}}
\preto\section{\everypar{}}
\preto\subsection{\everypar{}}
\preto\subsubsection{\everypar{}}   

\newlength{\parnumberheight}
\setlength{\parnumberheight}{1.5ex} % set paragraph numbers height <<<<<<<<<<
\definecolor{paranumcolor}{rgb}{0.82, 0.1, 0.26} % set color of numbers (red) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\definecolor{paranumcolor}{rgb}{0.52, 0.52, 0.51}% set color of numbers (gray)

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\setnumberedparagraph}
\newsavebox{\numberedparagraph}

\newcommand{\numberedparagraph@set}[1][2ex]{%
    \sbox{\setnumberedparagraph}{\resizebox{!}{#1}
        {\color{paranumcolor}\itshape\thechapter.\refstepcounter{para}\thepara\space}%
    }%
\usebox{\setnumberedparagraph}
}

\newcommand{\parnumber@insert}[1][2ex]{%
    \sbox{\numberedparagraph}{\numberedparagraph@set[#1]}%
    \makebox[-\parindent][r]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\usebox\numberedparagraph}}%
}

\renewcommand{\@afterheading}{%
        \@nobreaktrue
        \everypar{%
        \bgroup%
        \everypar{}%
        \if@nobreak%
        \@nobreakfalse%
        \clubpenalty\@M%
        \if@afterindent%
        \else%
        {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
        \fi%
        \else%
        \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty%
        \fi%
        \parnumber@insert[\parnumberheight]%
        \egroup%
    }%
}   
\makeatother        
%*****************************************************  changed<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}        
    
    \chapter{Title}
        
    \section{Sample Section}
    
    \lipsum[1-4]
    
    \subsection{Sample Subsection}
    
    \lipsum[11-15]
    
    \section{Another Section}
    
    \lipsum[18-26]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice!.. I noticed everypar doesn't "see" lists, and sees the TOC as paragraphs :) - this occurs in my MWE as well.

Comment: @baradhili Perhaps you should ask another question with a more extended example of your desired output